# generate a form based on object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any available plugin or gem which can generate a form based on some object that could be a hash or hash from yml.

Basically, wanted to create an app to mange other application configurations where I am going to read existing app-config files and create some form based on it to update from UI.

Suggests if there is an existing way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [formtastic](http://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/) you can do:

```
<% semantic_form_for @object do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs %>
  <%= f.buttons %>
<% end %>
```

And it will make form fields for every db column automatically.

For a plain hash object this might get you part of the way there:

```
config = { :host => 'localhost', :port => '3000', :path => 'foo/bar' }
<% form_tag set_config_path %>
  <% config.each do |key, value| %>
    <input type='text' name='<%= key %>' value='<%= value %>'/>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag 'save' %>
<% end %>
```

You may need to namespace the key names to fit the params key you want.

edit: Whoa, whoa. This Gem just came out today. Almost as if just for you:

https://github.com/joshsusser/informal

Comment: I know about formatastic, it generates form for activeRecord object not a hash object or yaml.

Comment: The gem looks very interesting. I wonder if formastic's magic will still work on it?